# Displaying Search results in SharePoint Online from a SharePoint 2010 environment

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, search, federated-search

Is there anyway to set up hybrid search to display SharePoint 2010 search results in SharePoint Online?  I am open to using SharePoint 2013 as an intermediary if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Hybrid connection from SP2013 (post SP1). You would have to crawl your 2010 farm from your 2013 farm and then configure Hybrid search. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197172.aspx